# If $\| f'-g'\|\leq l$ then $\| f-g\|\leq l$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

By  $L^2({-\infty},{+\infty})$ we denote the Hilbert space  of real functions that are square integrable in Lebesgue's sense:
$$L^2(\mathbb R)=\left\{f: \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx<+\infty\right\}$$
with respect to the inner product and $L^2$-norm that are
$$\langle f, g \rangle =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx\qquad \|f\| =\sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R)}}\, .$$
Let $f':=\frac{df}{dx}$ the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and let $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb R)$. If there exist a number $l>0$ such that $\| f'-g'\|\leq l$ is it possible to prove that $\|f-g\|\leq l$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly false. Take $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, given by
$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
-x e^x & \mbox{if} & x < - 1\mbox{;}
\\
\frac{1}{e} & \mbox{if} & x \in [- 1 , 1]\mbox{;}
\\
x e^{- x} & \mbox{if} & x > 1\mbox{.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This function belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and is derivable on $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$
f'(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
- (1 + x) e^x & \mbox{if} & x < - 1\mbox{;}
\\
0 & \mbox{if} & x \in [- 1 , 1]\mbox{;}
\\
(1 - x) e^{- x} & \mbox{if} & x > 1\mbox{.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
You have to show that
$$
||f|| = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2} e} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad ||f'|| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} e}\mbox{.}
$$
Note $l$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} e}$ and let $g$ be the null function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
||f' - g'|| \leq l \qquad \mbox{ but } \qquad ||f - g|| = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2} e} > l
$$
and it proves that your statement is false.